# How do I proceed to calculate this Z Transform?

Tags: z-transform

I would like to calculate the Z-Transform of following discrete signal:

$$x[n] = 3^{-|n|}$$

Plugging it into the known formula, I got:

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x[n]z^{-n} = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 3^{-|n|} z^{-n} = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{3}z^{-1})^{n} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 3^{-n}z^n
$$

I know the first term could be simplified like so:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{3}z^{-1})^{n} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}}$$

However, I have no idea how to simplify the second term:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 3^{-n}z^n$$

How do I simplify the second term, such as that I get a result which allows me to calculate the Z-Transform of $x[n]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little problem in your deriviation.

$$
x[n] = 3^{-|n|} = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
&3^{-n} & n\geq 0\\
&3^{n} & n<0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

So its $z$-transform is
$$
X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^{-n} z^{-n} + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}3^{n}z^{-n} 
$$
For the second term, let $m=-n$ and apply the well-known [geomitric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) summation formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
X(z)&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3z}\right)^{n} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{3} \right)^m\\
&= \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3z}} + \frac{\frac{z}{3}}{1-\frac{z}{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

To ensure the two infinite geometric series converge, it requires that
$$
|\frac{1}{3z}|<1
$$
and
$$
|\frac{z}{3}|<1
$$
Therefore the Region of Convergence of this $z$-transform is
$$
\frac{1}{3}<|z|<3
$$